# Use class member functions as callbacks?

Tags: c++

I would need a member function to be passed into a third party external method:

```
box_self_intersection_d(mycallback);
```

The `box_self_intersection_d` is a third party external static method, and I cannot modify it. `mycallback` is a method I want to pass it into the `box_self_intersection_d`, it is a class function and is accessing some members in this class ( have full control for this class and the `mycallback`)

Is there anyway I can use class member functions as callbacks without declaring them as static functions?

Edit: the signature of `mycallback` is `(const box &boxA, const box &boxB)`, where `box` is a special class from the third party provider.

And the [signature for](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.4/doc_html/cgal_manual/Box_intersection_d_ref/Function_box_self_intersection_d.html)  `box_self_intersection_d` is

```
void box_self_intersection_d(RandomAccessIterator begin,RandomAccessIterator end,Callback callback)
```

Comment: Does this approach even make sense? Remember that a non-static member function only makes sense in the company of a class *instance*. So you need to pass both the member function *and* the instance to the callback somehow, but which instance?

Comment: If the method is fixed and cannot be changed, then a good to have bit of information in the question is what the signature of that method is, as that determines the constraints of the problem.

Comment: Was there any solution for this problem? I face exactly the same issue, but although some answers were up-voted, none of them was marked as accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the function `box_self_intersection_d` takes a functional as parameters, and `mycallback` is a method of a class `MyClass`, you can use `boost::bind`:

```
box_self_intersection_d( boost::bind( &MyClass::mycallback, myClassInstance ) );
```

where `myClassInstance` is the instance of the class `MyClass`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this only work with `static T MyClass::mycallback(MyClass* self)` (implemented as `return self->mycallback()`) or also with only the more common `T MyClass::mycallback()`? I'm not familiar with boost, so I'm wondering if you need the extra wrapper (from what I can see on the online documentation you need it).

Comment: @bitmask: I am unsure of the question, but if you refer only to the `boost::bind`, yes it will work to bind a non-static member function that takes no arguments and/or a static member function that takes a single argument of type pointer to `MyClass`. I fear that this is not a real answer to the question, as it seems that the signature of `box_self_intersection_d` cannot be changed, and I doubt that it takes a functor.

Comment: @bitmask Yes: `boost::bind` works with both. In particular, with a non static member function `void MyClass::mycallback()` (I think this is the case of the original question)

Answer (score 1):

If the callback accepts a void* for user-defined data, you can use a static wrapper function that casts the void* argument to the class type and calls your member function.

Example:

```
static void Foo::callback_method(void* data) {
    static_cast<Foo*>(data)->mycallback();
}

void Foo::register_my_callback() {
    box_self_intersection_d(&Foo::callback_method, this);
}
```

Most sane callback libraries allow you to pass this void* argument to the functions as a way to have user-defined data in it. If not, you'll need to resort to the dirty method:

```
static Foo* Foo::callback_object;
static void Foo::callback_method() {
    callback_object->mycallback();
}

void Foo::register_my_callback() {
    callback_object = this;
    box_self_intersection_d(&Foo::callback_method);
}
```

In general, if you need to pass a function, there is just no other way: Either you have a data side-channel like the void*, which your library provider seems to have omitted (and is clearly a bug in the library), or you need to transport the this pointer via a global variable.

Comment: can you be more explicit? And bear in mind that the method which calls the callback is not under my control

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible workarounds. You can have a look here: http://www.newty.de/fpt/callback.html#member

In short, you can either:

- declare a static "wrapper method" and pass the instance of the class to it,
- or else store a pointer to the object as a global variable.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I think both solutions are not applicable for my situation. For 1, it requires me to modify the `mycallback` method signature, which is not possible. For 2, well... let's just say that I hate global variable because of potential threading issues.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the signature  `box_self_intersection_d()`

in general, if the signature is

```
void box_self_intersection_d( void *cb );
```

or even

```
void box_self_intersection_d( void (*cb)(const box&, const box&) );
```

then you cannot pass it a pointer to a member function.

The reason is that `sizeof(a_member_function)` is different than
`sizeof(a_function_pointer)`. If this is the case, I think you are forced to use *thiton*'s solution, and create a static function.

Comment: The signature of `box_self_intersection_d` is void 
`box_self_intersection_d (  RandomAccessIterator begin,
RandomAccessIterator end,
Callback callback)`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's CGAL, the callback is actually a template parameter.
Its only constraints are "Callback must be of the BinaryFunction concept".
That is, it can be anything that is "callable" with the proper parameters.

This includes any object with a `void operator() (const box&, const box&)` member function.
Implementing that function in your class and passing `*this` for the callback would probably be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a horrible solution that I can conceive of that means copying/pushing 'this' and function code to the calling stack, (or some other caller-allocated segment that can be made writeable and executable), and passing the address of the function to the library.  The called-back function could then find its own code address, extract 'this' using an offset/pointer arith. and call a member function.  Should work for multiple threads.

I hereby claim this years 'Gruesome Hack' award for a solution that makes developers feel physically ill but might still actually work if a project manager is pointing a shotgun at your head.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Yeah, (before someone else moans), the caller stack would be no good for an anychronous callback - need a separate R/E segment that can be dellocated in the callback.  Even messier :((