# How to use a C++ member function as an interrupt handler in Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

Arduino's [`attachInterrupt`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/) requires a callback function of type `void(*)()`, but I'd like to pass it a member function instead.  I can't use a C++ member function here because of its implicit `this` argument.

### Background

I know it's possible to use C++ member functions as callbacks.  For example, FreeRTOS' [`xTaskCreate(...)`](https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html) takes a callback function of type `void(*)(*)`.
[isocpp.org has a nice FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#memfnptr-vs-fnptr-more) on the use of member functions as callbacks.

In this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7885738/8453543) user thiton writes:

> Most sane callback libraries allow you to pass this void* argument to the functions as a way to have user-defined data in it

Perhaps the Arduino library is not "sane?" or perhaps this is design decision made to simplify the Arduino API?

#### it's there... inside `attachInterrupt`

I'm programming for an ESP32.  [In the `arduino-esp32` implementation of `attachInterrupt`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/FunctionalInterrupt.cpp#L16), there's a function called `__attachInterruptFunctionalArg(...)` that seems to do exactly what I want, but since it's not part of the Arduino API, I'm hesitant to include it in a project that's for public consumption because it may break.

### Example program

```cpp
// An attempt to summarize https://github.com/pierremolinaro/acan2517/issues/4

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <functional>

#define IRAM_ATTR __attribute__((section(".iram1")))

// from `esp32-hal-gpio.c`
typedef void (*voidFuncPtrArg)(void*);
extern void __attachInterruptFunctionalArg(uint8_t pin, voidFuncPtrArg userFunc, void * arg, int intr_type, bool functional);

// from Arduino `FunctionalInterrupt.cpp`
void attachInterrupt(uint8_t pin, std::function<void(void)> intRoutine, int mode);

void IRAM_ATTR interruptFunctional(void* arg);

// from Arduino `FunctionalInterrupt.h`
struct InterruptArgStructure {
    std::function<void(void)> interruptFunction;
};

// from ACAN2517
class ACAN2517
{
    public: ACAN2517 (const int interrupt_pin);
    public: void begin (void (* inInterruptServiceRoutine) (void));
    public: void begin_functional (void (* inInterruptServiceRoutine) (void *), void *);
    public: void isr(void);
    private: const int interrupt_pin;
};

ACAN2517::ACAN2517 (const int interrupt_pin):
    interrupt_pin(interrupt_pin)
{};

#define FALLING 0

// This won't work with a member function
void ACAN2517::begin (void (* inInterruptServiceRoutine) (void)) {
    attachInterrupt(interrupt_pin, inInterruptServiceRoutine, FALLING);
}

// This will, but is prone to breakage when the Arduino internals change
void ACAN2517::begin_functional (void (* inInterruptServiceRoutine) (void *), void *arg)
{
    __attachInterruptFunctionalArg(interrupt_pin, inInterruptServiceRoutine, arg, FALLING, true);
}

void ACAN2517::isr(void)
{
    printf("fhtagn");
}

//===
// User code begin
//===

#define N_DRIVERS 3

ACAN2517 g_driver(23);  // Initializing a driver instance statically
ACAN2517 *drivers[N_DRIVERS];

void call_ACAN_isr(void *arg)
{
    ACAN2517 *driver = (ACAN2517 *)arg;
    driver->isr();
}

int main()
{
    g_driver.begin( []{g_driver.isr();} ); // No problem

    for (int i = 0; i < N_DRIVERS; i++)
    {
        drivers[i] = &ACAN2517(i);
        drivers[i]->begin( []{drivers[i]->isr();} );
        // ERROR
        // static void lambda []void ()->void::_FUN()
        // an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N_DRIVERS; i++)
    {
        drivers[i] = &ACAN2517(i);
        drivers[i]->begin( [i]{drivers[i]->isr();} );
        // ERROR
        // no suitable conversion function from "lambda []void ()->void" to "void (*)()" exists
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N_DRIVERS; i++)
    {
        drivers[i] = &ACAN2517(i);
        ACAN2517 *driver = drivers[i];
        drivers[i]->begin_functional( [driver]{driver->isr();}, driver);
        // Not sure how to get this to work in a lambda...
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N_DRIVERS; i++)
    {
        drivers[i] = &ACAN2517(i);
        ACAN2517 *driver = drivers[i];
        drivers[i]->begin_functional( call_ACAN_isr, driver);
        // OK
    }
}

//===
// User code end
//===

// from esp32-hal-gpio.c
extern void __attachInterruptFunctionalArg(uint8_t pin, voidFuncPtrArg userFunc, void * arg, int intr_type, bool functional)
{
    // ...
}

// from Arduino `FunctionalInterrupt.cpp`
void attachInterrupt(uint8_t pin, std::function<void(void)> intRoutine, int mode)
{
    // use the local interrupt routine which takes the ArgStructure as argument
    __attachInterruptFunctionalArg (pin, (voidFuncPtrArg)interruptFunctional, new InterruptArgStructure{intRoutine}, mode, true);
}

void IRAM_ATTR interruptFunctional(void* arg)
{
    InterruptArgStructure* localArg = (InterruptArgStructure*)arg;
    if (localArg->interruptFunction)
    {
      localArg->interruptFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good to check if that compiler have https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn  new arduino compilers have support for many C++11 features.

Comment: I seem a bit late to the party, but there is a library BindArg for Arduino for using object instance methods as interrupt handlers (https://github.com/openlab-vn-ua/BindArg). Instead of: `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(SOME_PIN), &MyClass::staticMethod, FALLING);` the code `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(SOME_PIN), bindArgGateThisAllocate(&MyClass::instanceMethod), this), FALLING);`
maybe used to provide the correct `this` for the instance method.
*This is the simplest solution if you use `detachInterrupt`, you should add the call `bindArgGateFree` after*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use a C++ member function here because of its implicit this argument.

Yes, that is exactly the problem and this can't be solved without extra code, if your API did not provide something what lets you store some additional data like the this pointer.

What you simply can do is:
Write your own `wrapper` and register the callback to the original handler. But that creates another indirection which increases the latency.

The other way is not as simple, but a bit less slow:
Write your `own interrupt handler` and callback registration. As you have the original sources of the arduino libs, you simply can replace the stuff around the `attachInterrupt` function.

Sorry, but there is no magic way to generate a data store for `this` without any additional software.

Comment: standard C++ got several ways to solve it

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: Shure! Write a wrapper! That is what I said!

Comment: Nowadays there is a library BindArg for Arduino for using object instance methods as interrupt handlers (https://github.com/openlab-vn-ua/BindArg). Instead of: `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(SOME_PIN), &MyClass::staticMethod, FALLING);` the code `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(SOME_PIN), bindArgGateThisAllocate(&MyClass::instanceMethod), this), FALLING);`
maybe used to provide the correct `this` for the instance method.